# Non-whitespace before first tag error

Tags: android, cordova

I can not build cordova application,and I receive the following error:

```
Error: Non-whitespace before first tag.
Line: 0
Column: 1
Char:
```

I am using `cordova 6.2.0`, and trying to build the `android` platform.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To overcome this error, just remove the platform and add it again:

```
Cordova platforms remove android
```

after removing, just add it again:

```
Cordova platforms add android
```

Finally build the platform:

```
Cordova build android
```

Thanks to [@ElDiabolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5440910/eldiabolo), if you are using Ionic, then you should prefix the aforementioned commands with `ionic` keyword. Read more about Ionic cli here:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/